# How to find the vectors of the cell A that contain at least one element of the vector B?

Tags: matlab, vector, cell, cell-array

How to find the vectors of `A` that contain at least one element of the vector `B` ?

example:

```
A = {[2 5],[8 9 2],[33 77 4],[102 6],[10 66 17 7 8 11],[110 99],[1 4 3],[15 41 88]}

B = [5 77 41 66 7]

Result = {[2 5],[33 77 4],[10 66 17 7 8 11],[15 41 88]}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Approaches

With `arrayfun` and `ismember` -

```
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(B,A{n})),1:numel(A)))
```

Or with `arrayfun` and `bsxfun` -

```
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(any(bsxfun(@eq,B(:),A{n}),2)),1:numel(A)))
```

Or with `arrayfun` and `setdiff` -

```
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) numel(setdiff(B,A{n})) < numel(B),1:numel(A)))
```

Or with `arrayfun` and `intersect` -

```
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) ~isempty(intersect(B,A{n})),1:numel(A)))
```

One could also use `cellfun` here, such that the four counterpart `cellfun` based solutions end up like these -

```
Result = A(cellfun(@(x) any(ismember(B,x)), A))

Result = A(cellfun(@(x) any(any(bsxfun(@eq,B(:),x),2)),A))

Result = A(cellfun(@(x) numel(setdiff(B,x)) < numel(B),A))

Result = A(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(intersect(B,x)),A))
```

**Taking different route [Using `bsxfun`'s masking capability]**

Rather than going into those `arrayfun` or `cellfun` based approaches that are essentially loopy approaches, one can make the solution *alot* vectorized by converting `A` into a 2D numeric array. So, the idea here is to have a `2D` array in which number of rows is the maximum number of elements in `A`  and number of columns as number of cells in `A`. Each column of this array would hold elements from each cell of `A` and `NaNs` would fill up the *empty spaces*.

The solution code with such an approach would look like this -

```
lens = cellfun('length',A); %// number of elements in each cell of A
mask = bsxfun(@ge,lens,(1:max(lens))'); %//'# mask of valid places in the 2D array
A_arr = NaN(size(mask)); %//initialize 2D array in which A elements are to be put
A_arr(mask) = [A{:}]; %// put the elements from A

%// Find if any element from B is in any element along the row or dim-3       
%// locations in A_arr. Then logically index into A with it for the final
%// cell array output
Result = A(any(any(bsxfun(@eq,A_arr,permute(B,[1 3 2])),1),3));
```

---

### Verification

```
>> celldisp(Result)
Result{1} =
     2     5
Result{2} =
    33    77     4
Result{3} =
    10    66    17     7     8    11
Result{4} =
    15    41    88
```

---

### Benchmarking

For people interested in seeing the runtime performances, here's a quick benchmarking test with a sufficiently huge datasize -

```
%// Create inputs
N = 10000; %// datasize
max_num_ele = 100; %// max elements in any cell of A
num_ele = randi(max_num_ele,N,1); %// number of elements in each cell of A
A = arrayfun(@(n) randperm(N,num_ele(n)), 1:N, 'uni', 0); 
B = randperm(N,num_ele(1));

%// Warm up tic/toc.
for k = 1:100000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

%// Start timing all approaches
disp('************************  With arrayfun **************************')
disp('------------------------  With arrayfun + ismember')
tic
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(ismember(B,A{n})),1:numel(A)));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With arrayfun + bsxfun')
tic
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) any(any(bsxfun(@eq,B(:),A{n}),2)),1:numel(A)));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With arrayfun + setdiff')
tic
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) numel(setdiff(B,A{n})) < numel(B),1:numel(A)));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With arrayfun + intersect')
tic
Result = A(arrayfun(@(n) ~isempty(intersect(B,A{n})),1:numel(A)));
toc, clear Result

disp('************************  With cellfun **************************')
disp('------------------------  With cellfun + ismember')
tic
Result = A(cellfun(@(x)any(ismember(B,x)), A));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With cellfun + bsxfun')
tic
Result = A(cellfun(@(x) any(any(bsxfun(@eq,B(:),x),2)),A));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With cellfun + setdiff')
tic
Result = A(cellfun(@(x) numel(setdiff(B,x)) < numel(B),A));
toc, clear Result

disp('------------------------  With cellfun + setdiff')
tic
Result = A(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(intersect(B,x)),A));

disp('************************  With masking bsxfun **************************')
tic
lens = cellfun('length',A); %// number of elements in each cell of A
mask = bsxfun(@ge,lens,(1:max(lens))'); %//'
A_numarr = NaN(size(mask));
A_numarr(mask) = [A{:}];
Result = A(any(any(bsxfun(@eq,A_numarr,permute(B,[1 3 2])),1),3));
toc
```

The results thus obtained on my system were -

```
************************  With arrayfun **************************
------------------------  With arrayfun + ismember
Elapsed time is 0.409810 seconds.
------------------------  With arrayfun + bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.157327 seconds.
------------------------  With arrayfun + setdiff
Elapsed time is 1.154602 seconds.
------------------------  With arrayfun + intersect
Elapsed time is 1.081729 seconds.
************************  With cellfun **************************
------------------------  With cellfun + ismember
Elapsed time is 0.392375 seconds.
------------------------  With cellfun + bsxfun
Elapsed time is 0.143341 seconds.
------------------------  With cellfun + setdiff
Elapsed time is 1.101331 seconds.
------------------------  With cellfun + setdiff
************************  With masking bsxfun ********************
Elapsed time is 0.067224 seconds.
```

As one can see, `cellfun` based solutions are wee bit faster than their `arrayfun` based counterparts! Also, mask-based `bsxfun` approach looks like an interesting one, but do keep in mind it's *memory-hungry nature*.

Comment: I can't even type that fast. +1

Comment: @thewaywewalk would you? not just `A(cellfun(@(x)any(ismember(B,x)), A))`?

Comment: @Dan, yes I just wanted to post it, that the shortest!

Comment: @Dan Added a link for the benchmark comparisons. Runtime really was the motivation for me to go with `arrayfun`.

Comment: @Dan It would be nice to see alternative solutions. So, maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: @Divakar I think it's fine to just add it into your answer if you'd like to, otherwise it's in the comments. Hardly seems necessary to make an answer out of it.

Comment: @Divakar: I'm running R2014a and for the test case: `N = 1000; A = arrayfun(@(n) randi(n,1,n), 1:N, 'uni', 0); B = randi(N,1,N/2);` the `cellfun` solution is actually the fastest!

Comment: @knedlsepp Did a quick test and yes seems like `cellfun` would be faster! I might add that info soon.

Comment: @knedlsepp Added the runtime results!